# how to load large amount of data in datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, ado.net

In my mvc application we need to load more than 100000 record at a time but while retrieving such amount of data my browser get crashed..

following is my code

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM DBO.MY_TEST_DATA";
//MSSQL CONNECTION STRING
string myCnString = "Data Source=MYIPSERVER;Initial Catalog=my_database;
Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=myPwd";
DataTable dt = GetDataTable(myCnString, sql);
//Todo: Use the table data

    public DataTable GetDataTable(string cnString, string sql)
    {
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cnString))
        {
         cn.Open();

            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cn))
            {
             da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 120;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                return ds.Tables[0];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A user cannot possibly absorb that much information on a page. Use server side paging.

Comment: Why would you do this? Nobody will have to look at 100000+ datarows. If you want to transfer them offer them as a download or a webservice. If you want to display data only transfer relevant data.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not a good convention. Look into pagination and serve the datarows to the client one batch at a time (the page size). You can use the native ASP.NET Data Grid or can go for a third party datagrid like jQuery DataTables.

Answer (score -1):

Bhagyashree, It will be much much better to get it done with server side paging. It also improves the performance of the application as well. If you are not aware about how to implement then you can look at [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1118363/GridView-with-Server-Side-Filtering-Sorting-and-Pa) and you can also get more help from Google as well !

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can solve this problem by using the advantages of paging .

Pagination is the process of displaying a huge number of records by splitting them into different pages. This can be better explained by a example. Consider you have 10000 records in a table you want to show them to the end user when he requests. The very simple thing is to display all of them by fetching from database with a simple select * from  query. OK fine you are done and your job is over. You have checked in the code...[Continue reading](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/485531/ASP-NET-Pagination)

if you want to implement paging without any third party plugin ,kindly refer the following link:https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Paging-Pagination-example-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

Hope the information was helpful

Thanks

Karthik